# Get prepared data in post request in aiohttp before sending request

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I use aiohttp for making post requests. I need to obtain prepared data in post request before sending request. So I try to find a method in aiohttp working similar to method [prepare](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) in requests library. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a proof-of-concept workaround in aiohttp to get the request's body before sending it, and perform an action (such as signing and adding a signature header, typically) at the same time.

DISCLAIMER: I do not recommend using this in a production environment (or a serious occasion). Because it relies on non-public and undocumented functions or properties in aiohttp. It may break anytime if the internal implementation of aiohttp changes.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import hashlib
import hmac

SECRET_KEY = '__SECRET_KEY__'


class HMACBodySignClientRequest(aiohttp.ClientRequest):
    def update_body_from_data(self, body) -> None:
        """bad: hook this internal method to get body and inject signature (may fail anytime if internal changes)"""
        super().update_body_from_data(body)

        if body is None:  # use `body` rather than `self.body` is expected.
            return

        body = self.body._value or b''  # bad: access to protected property (may not available)
        signature = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY.encode('utf-8'), body, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
        self.headers['X-Signature'] = signature.hexdigest()


async def aiohttp_body_sign_workaround():
    url = 'https://httpbin.org/api'
    data = {'foo': 'bar'}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            request_class=HMACBodySignClientRequest) as session:  # <-- auto add signature via `request_class`
        async with session.post(url=url, json=data) as response:
            print(response.request_info)


asyncio.run(aiohttp_body_sign_workaround())
```

Tested on aiohttp 3.8.5, may fail in any other version.

Please be aware that this approach is a form of 'black magic' and may only work in certain trivial cases, such as small data or non-streaming requests. Use at your own risk.

---

###### How does it work?

In the current internal design of aiohttp, there is an internal property `_request_class: ClientRequest` on `ClientSession`, which delegates the actual request generation.

At some point, the request body bytes MAY become available to get.

It is found that after the `ClientRequest` method `update_body_from_data()` gets called, accessing `self.body._value` MAY reveal the body bytes.

And fortunately, the `_request_class` property can be specified when initializing a `ClientSession` with the `request_class` argument. This means we can subclass `ClientRequest` and override/hook the `update_body_from_data()` method to add our custom logic (in this case, adding an HMAC signature of the body to the header).

Yes, it relies on internal details, so as I have said, it is just a proof-of-concept.