# aiohttp: How to update request headers according to request body?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am trying to implement a type of custom authentication by using aiohttp something like the example in [this link](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-authentication) but I also need request body. Here is an example for [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
class CustomAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, secretkey):
        self.secretkey = secretkey

    def get_hash(self, request):
        if request.body:
            data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        else:
            data = "{}"

        signature = hmac.new(
            str.encode(self.secretkey),
            msg=str.encode(data),
            digestmod=hashlib.sha256
        ).hexdigest().upper()
        return signature

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.headers["CUSTOM-AUTH"] = self.get_hash(request)
        return request
```

I've looked into [tracing](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/tracing_reference.html) and [BasicAuth](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#basicauth) but they are useless in my situation. On `on_request_start` request body is not ready, on `on_request_chunk_sent` headers have already been sent. A solution like BasicAuth don't have access the request data at all.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following solution (it is not elegant as the request's solution):

```py
def get_hash(secret_key, data=None):
    if data is None:
        data = "{}"
    else:
        data = json.dumps(data)

    signature = (
        hmac.new(str.encode(secretkey), msg=str.encode(data), digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
        .hexdigest()
        .upper()
    )
    return signature


async def request(session, type, path, params, data, headers, secret_key):
    headers["CUSTOM-AUTH"] = get_hash(secret_key, data)
    return await session.request(type, path, params=params, json=data, headers=headers)


# example usage
url = "" # your url
data = {} # your data
headers = {} # your headers
secret_key = "" # your secret key
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    response = await request(session, "post", url, None, data, headers, secret_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I have found a proof-of-concept workaround.

---

[I have posted more details in another, more general question discussing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76776457/9164600). However, I believe leaving the essential code and notes here would also be beneficial for the convenience of future readers. This is because the original question that I came across was this one, where I had the same need to add an HMAC signature of the body to the header in aiohttp in a convenient way.

---

DISCLAIMER: I do not recommend using this in a production environment (or a serious occasion). Because it relies on non-public and undocumented functions or properties in aiohttp. It may break anytime if the internal implementation of aiohttp changes.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import hashlib
import hmac

SECRET_KEY = '__SECRET_KEY__'


class HMACBodySignClientRequest(aiohttp.ClientRequest):
    def update_body_from_data(self, body) -> None:
        """bad: hook this internal method to get body and inject signature (may fail anytime if internal changes)"""
        super().update_body_from_data(body)

        if body is None:  # use `body` rather than `self.body` is expected.
            return

        body = self.body._value or b''  # bad: access to protected property (may not available)
        signature = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY.encode('utf-8'), body, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
        self.headers['X-Signature'] = signature.hexdigest()


async def aiohttp_body_sign_workaround():
    url = 'https://httpbin.org/api'
    data = {'foo': 'bar'}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            request_class=HMACBodySignClientRequest) as session:  # <-- auto add signature via `request_class`
        async with session.post(url=url, json=data) as response:
            print(response.request_info)


asyncio.run(aiohttp_body_sign_workaround())
```

Tested on aiohttp 3.8.5 (2023-7), may fail in any other version.

Please be aware that this approach is a form of 'black magic' and may only work in certain trivial cases, such as small data or non-streaming requests. Use at your own risk.